# order by with group by sub query not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, subquery

I have a simple stats query in mysql. 
I had it working using php but was keen to keep it in the database so I found another question on it here. Thanks to that I have it working in mysql now.

I need to get a running total count of records submitted per day.

I have the running total working but no matter what I change it simply will not order by day.

It will order by the running total column but not the day.

Any input is appreciated.

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT
   q1.`Day` AS 'Days of month',
   q1.`Record count` AS 'Record count',
   (@runtot := @runtot +  q1.`Record count`) AS 'rt'
FROM
   (SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(tr.`tr_last_update`, '%e') AS 'Day',
    COUNT(tr.tr_id_pk) AS 'Record Count'
    FROM records_table AS tr
    GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(tr.`tr_last_update`,'%e')
) AS q1
ORDER BY 'Days of month';

Days of month   Record count    rt
10                  13          13
11                  2           15
7                   255         270
8                   173         443
9                   166         609
```

Comment: yeah, I had thought of that too and tried it but no joy I'm afraid, thanks anyway though for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being treated as a string.  Try casting to an int:

```
SELECT
q1.`Day` AS 'Days of month',
...
ORDER BY CAST(q1.`Day` AS signed integer)
```

Comment: Just tried it, but it throws a syntax error, it tells me to check my syntax. checked for typeo's but its typed correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dbaseman: whatever it is being treated I guess `order by` always works.

Comment: @jiraiya see my update ... I guess you have to cast to "signed integer" (casting to "int" doesn't work).

Comment: @dbaseman great stuff, I was just looking up the mysql syntax for the signed integer when your update came through :) super fast work indeed. Thanks so much for this it has solved my problem. One edit for people looking in the future, it works with the actual CAST in the order by clause as you had put originally. The alias in the order by clause won't work. Thanks again. I will accept the answer in about 2 minutes when SO lets me.

Comment: @jiraiya Thanks for your note- I updated my answer.  (Although I'm not quite sure why using *ORDER BY 'Days of month'* didn't work, as it seemed to work for me when I tested in Workbench.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm much mistaken, isn't your whole query the same as:

```
SELECT   DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tr_last_update)) AS `Days of month`,
         COUNT(tr_id_pk)                           AS `Record Count`,
         @runtot := @runtot + COUNT(tr_id_pk)      AS rt
FROM     records_table, (SELECT @runtot:=0) AS z
GROUP BY `Days of month`
ORDER BY `Days of month`
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this query, but the running totals come out all wrong for some reason. I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: @jiraiya: My bad, the expression assigned to `@runtot` should have been `+ COUNT(tr_id_pk)` instead of just `+ tr_id_pk`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: No problem at all. I should have noticed it myself but deadline pressure and Monday morning eyes are having a negative effect on me. It runs now but the @runtot column is being reset for each row so instead of being cumulative it its just the same as the daily count.

Comment: @jiraiya: Maybe get rid of the joined initialisation table and just initialise `@runtot` as you were before, with a `SET` statement prior to the `SELECT`?